# Difference: probability of having a sample mean smaller than x and the probability of having an individual value smaller than x

Tags: probability, statistical-inference

What’s the difference in practical terms between calculating the probability of having a sample mean smaller than x and the probability of an individual of a population having a value smaller than x?

For example: assume I am studying my travel time from home to office. I take a sample of 30 values. I can calculate: A) the probability of having a mean smaller than 60 minutes. B) The probability of a single trip taken by chance to last up to 60 minutes.

Let’s say I want to analyze the risk of arriving in the office after 60 minutes. Which approach would better represent this point? I’d like to understand the differences of these 2 approaches in real life decision making.

Comment: The mean would have lower variance, since it is an average of multiple measurements. This means that more extreme events are less likely when you consider the distribution of means, rather than the distribution of a single journey.

Comment: Let's say I want to analyze the risk of arriving in the office after 60 minutes, what value this lower variance would add to the analysis?

Comment: The variance is decreased based on the number of measurements you take rather than _what_ you are measuring. So if you took 30 measurements say, then the variance changes from $\sigma^2$ to $\sigma^2/30$.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the "mean" is not a random variable. However, when speaking of the "mean" you probably mean the "sample mean". The latter is the mean you observe after seeing 30 samples.
(A) The event of having a sample mean < 60 minutes is the event of on average arriving within 60 minutes.
(B) The event of having a single trip < 60 minutes is the event of on arriving on that particular day within 60 minutes.

Comment: Yes, "sample mean", I have edited after your comment to make it clearer.